# Finding the column index given the contents in a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, cell-array

I am trying to figure out how to get the column index when given the 2 row values in a 2-row cell array.

I don't know why I am having difficulty figuring this out because you can easily was find for 1 column value.

For example, give the cell array below:

```
{1,1,1,2,2,2;'apple','banana','orange','apple','banana','orange'}.'
```

I want to find where column1 = `2`, and column2 = `'banana'`

The output should be 5.

How would I do this?

Comment: that's a cell array right?

Comment: That looks like a 1D cell array of values.  I think you meant a 2D matrix / cell array

Comment: You surely mean `{1,1,1,2,2,2;'apple','banana','orange','apple','banana','orange'}.'`. Please edit the question accordingly

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, sorry. I meant cell array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume a cell array, according to @LuisMendo

```
cellarray = {1,1,1,2,2,2;'apple','banana','orange','apple','banana','orange'}.';
values = cell2mat(cellarray(:,1));
tmp1 = values == 1;
tmp2 = strcmp('banana', cellarray(:,2));
tmp3 = tmp1+tmp2;
result = find(tmp3 == 2);
```

This will get the values from the cell array, then searches for all values equal to `1`. Then it uses [`strcmp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to find all matches with `'banana'` and adds that result to the logical array obtained by value. Finally it searches for where both instances are true, i.e. where `tmp3` equals `2`.

Whoohoo! My first golfed one liner. 59, 51 bytes!

```
find(((([A{:,1}])==1)'+strcmp('banana',A(:,2)))==2)
 =
         2
```

Comment: You probably mean `values = cell2mat(cellarray(:,1))`. Or `values = [cellarray{:,1}]`

Comment: @LuisMendo I did indeed. Coulnd't get the strings in that way however, gave me a CAT error

Comment: Yes, with strings you need to keep then as a cell array, because they may have different lengths. But `strcmp` looks into the cell's contents, so you use it to compare a cell array of strings with a string

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Adriaan I can not run the line tmp3 = tmp1+tmp2; due to a matrix dimensions mismatch.

Comment: Should've been a logical as well. See the updated answer.

Comment: This was your first one-liner? Huh, well more to come I hope!

Comment: @Divakar I did this by merely substituting all variables for their definitions and hoping for the best. I guess I need to learn more special functions and improve my logicals to get shorter still.

Comment: That you will, just keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are into `code-golfing` -

```
find([A{1,:}]==2 & ismember(A(2,:),'banana'))
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A = 
    [    1]    [     1]    [     1]    [    2]    [     2]    [     2]
    'apple'    'banana'    'orange'    'apple'    'banana'    'orange'
>> find([A{1,:}]==2 & ismember(A(2,:),'banana'))
ans =
     5
```

Comment: Within 7 characters now, almost there!

Comment: @Adriaan How about, replacing `ismember` with `strcmp`? I didn't want to use that, because you did :)

Comment: Then again, I'd never use `&`, but always `&&`. Could be because MATLAB keeps telling me to, could be because I like to visually separate the two variables

Comment: checked it, `strcmp` requires you to transpose either array. Thus `strcmp'` is seven characters, `ismember` is 8. Not that great an improvement